# NHibernate - Left joins

Tags: nhibernate, join, left-join, outer-join

I have the following two tables:

**Jobs** AreaID, JobNo (composite key)

**Logs** LogID, AreaID, JobNo

I need to get all jobs that don't have any logs associated with them. In SQL I could do:

```
SELECT Jobs.AreaID,
       Jobs.JobNo
FROM   Jobs
       LEFT JOIN Logs
           ON Jobs.AreaID = Logs.AreaID
           AND Jobs.JobNo = Logs.JobNo
WHERE  Logs.LogID is null
```

But I'm not sure how to accomplish this with NHibernate. Could anyone offer any pointers?

Here are my mappings:

```
<class name="Job" table="Jobs">
    <composite-key name="Id">
        <key-property name="JobNo"/>
        <key-many-to-one name="Area" class="Area" column="AreaID"/>
    </composite-key>
</class>

<class name="Log" table="Logs">
    <id name="Id" column="LogID">
        <generator class="identity"/>
    </id>
    <property name="JobNo"/>
    <many-to-one name="Area" class="Area" column="AreaID"/>
</class>
```

Thanks

**Update**

OK, I modified Nosila's answer slightly, and this is now doing what I wanted:

```
Log logs = null;

return session.QueryOver<Job>()
    .Left.JoinAlias(x => x.Logs, () => logs)
    .Where(x => logs.Id == null)
    .List<Job>();
```

I also had to add this to my Job mapping:

```
<bag name="Logs">
    <key>
        <column name="JobNo"></column>
        <column name="DivisionID"></column>
    </key>
    <one-to-many class="Log"/>
</bag>
```

Thanks for the help. :)

Comment: Can you post the query you have now?

Comment: The above SQL query is currently what I'm using. I'm just learning NH at the moment and am trying to convert a small application over to using it.

Comment: Do you have your mappings created? Also, someone correct me if I'm wrong but I think you need NHibernate 3.2 in order to add conditions to your join (using the `QueryOver` API, anyways).

Comment: Yep, I've included my mappings above.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I'm not familiar with composite identifiers as I don't use them so for all I know NHibernate will automatically create the proper left join. None the less, the (non-tested) query below should get you started.

```
Job jobAlias = null;
Log logAlias = null;
YourDto yourDto = null;

session.QueryOver<Job>()
    // Here is where we set what columns we want to project (e.g. select)
    .SelectList(x => x
        .Select(x => x.AreaID).WithAlias(() => jobAlias.AreaID)
        .Select(x => x.JobNo).WithAlias(() => jobAlias.JobNo)
    )
    .Left.JoinAlias(x => x.Logs, () => logAlias, x.JobNo == logAlias.JobNo)
    .Where(() => logAlias.LogID == null)
    // This is where NHibernate will transform what you have in your `SelectList()` to a list of objects
    .TransformUsing(Transformers.AliasToBean<YourDto>())
    .List<YourDto>();

public class YourDto
{
    public int AreaID { get; set; }
    public int JobNo { get; set; }
}
```

Note: You need NHibernate 3.2 in order to set join conditions.

Comment: Thanks. I'm gonna have to mull over this one (there's a few errors in it). It also seems extremely complex for such a simple query.

Comment: @Tom I agree with the complexity, writing this in SQL would be much simpler.  I feel the ORM abstraction is getting out of hand.

Answer (score 5):

```
Job job = null;
var jobsWithoutLogs = session.QueryOver(() => job)
    .WithSubquery.WhereNotExists(QueryOver.Of<Log>()
        .Where(log => log.Job == job)
        .Select(Projections.Id()))
    .List()
```

Update: i saw you added the mapping. The Above Code only works for the following mapping

```
<class name="Log" table="Logs">
    <id name="Id" column="LogID">
        <generator class="identity"/>
    </id>
    <many-to-one name="Job" >
      <column name="JobNo"/>
      <column name="AreaID"/>
    <many-to-one />
</class>
```

Comment: Nice. I like this solution better.

Comment: This does seem easier, although I'm getting the error "Cannot use subqueries on a criteria without a projection". Also, is this going to be a more expensive query since it's using subqueries instead of a simple left join?

Comment: 1) added projection. 2) i don't think its more expensive since its doing the same thing. you could check the query plan

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, but I've used Nosila's answer and modified it slightly (see my first post). :)