# Add additional conditional to JOIN and not WHERE clause

Tags: nhibernate

I've been trying to accomplish this for a few days using QueryOver without much progress.  I can't seem to find a way to add a conditional on a left outer join on a one to many relationship.  I have Question and Answer entities, where a Question has multiple Answers (it's for a Survey, where each response is another Answer to the same Question).  I'm trying to filter all the Answers based on some criteria (for example, all answers with a Score < 3), but anytime I attempt to add the conditional, it gets added to the WHERE clause and not on the JOIN.

## Example entities

Question:

```
public class Question : Entity<int>
{
    public virtual IEnumerable<Answer> Answers { get; set; }
    ...
}
```

Answer:

```
public class Answer : Entity<int>
{
    public virtual Question Question { get; set; }
    public virtual int Score { get; set; }
    ...
}
```

## Queries

I've tried many different variants of using JoinQueryOver...

```
session.QueryOver<Question>()
    .Where(q => q.Survey.Id == id)
    .Left.JoinQueryOver(q => q.Answers)
    .Where(a => a.Score < 3)
```

...and JoinAlias and using the alias in the Where

```
session.QueryOver<Question>(() => questionAlias)
    .Where(q => q.Survey.Id == id)
    .Left.JoinAlias(() => questionAlias.Answers, () => answerAlias)
    .Where(() => answerAlias.Score > 3);
```

I always get a query like this:

```
SELECT * FROM QUESTION q
left outer join ANSWER a on q.Id=a.Question_id
WHERE q.Survey_id = 1 and a.Score < 3
```

but I need:

```
SELECT * FROM QUESTION q
left outer join ANSWER a on q.Id=a.Question_id and a.Score < 3
WHERE q.Survey_id = 1
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Turns out I was using an older version of NHibernate (3.1) that didn't support this, but upgrading to 3.3 now has an additional withClause you can pass, like so:

```
Answer answerAlias = null;
var questionQuery = session.QueryOver<Question>()
    .Where(q => q.Survey.Id == id)
    .Left.JoinQueryOver(q => q.Answers, () => answerAlias, a => a.Score > 3);
```

I believe this is supported as of 3.2 (the accepted answer on this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9293424/nhibernate-left-joins) is what tipped me off)

Comment: I wish I could favourite answers. This helped me a lot, thanks!

Comment: So glad I found this answer, exactly what I have been looking for, thanks a lot

Comment: For the love of all that is right in the world! Thank you! I soooo wish nhibernate documentation was better.

Answer (score 0):

IIRC, the only query API that supports this is HQL:

```
from Question q
left join q.Answers a with a.Score < 3
where q.Survey.Id = :id
```

(untested)

Comment: Hmm, I'm trying to filter the Answer collection each Question, but still return Questions.  Is there another way to do this maybe using a subquery?  In other words, I don't want question.Answers to lazy load all Answers, but a filters subset of them.

Comment: You can't return an incomplete collection as part of an entity. Use a projection instead, or load the Question first, and then use `session.Filter(question.Answers, "where Score < 3")` to get a filtered subset of answers.